# How can a branch office reach my main office network?

Tags: vpn, firewall

I have a main office today with a Juniper firewall.

I need to create a branch office, which is located outside my network. The branch office is part of a "office community" with some sort of shared network/internet.

Can I install some hardware (like VPN) at the branch office, so it can reach my "main office" network?

If so, any products you can recommend?

Thanks.

Comment: If the network is shared with other users that do not belong to your company you would have to build your own (hardware) network in the branch or use individual VPN (each computer get's it's own software VON client).

Comment: vpn can satisfiy your needs:https://www.cnet.com/news/fastest-vpn/